# SeekBar StringIndexOutOfBoundsException with editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

advancing on my project, I am fighting with a problem I cannot solve..

Wanting to run a search function on a ListView so I used an EditText.

My problem: my method works well when I get two characters in the EditText and shows only items containing "Name" that I passed on it, but when I get a third character,then application crashes..

here is my log:

```
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; regionStart=0; regionLength=3
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at java.lang.String.subSequence(String.java:1861)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at com.android.bordeaux.code.MyListActivity$3.onTextChanged(MyListActivity.java:126)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8315)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:8362)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:8725)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:892)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:352)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:266)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:443)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:420)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:29)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:667)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:188)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:149)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:279)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
09-14 16:49:05.647: E/AndroidRuntime(20020):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And this is my code:

```
inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
                  {
                      textlength = inputSearch.getText().length();
                      String query = inputSearch.getText().toString();

                      arr_sort.clear();
                      for(int i=0;i < currentArray.size();i++)
                      {
                          if(textlength <= currentArray.get(i).getName().length())
                          {
                              String[] wordArray = currentArray.get(i).getName().split(" ");
                              for (int j = 0; j < wordArray.length; j++)
                              {
                                  if(query.equalsIgnoreCase((String) wordArray[j].subSequence(0, textlength)))
                                  {
                                      arr_sort.add(currentArray.get(i));
                                      break;
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                    list_adapter = new announcersListAdapter(MyListActivity.this, R.layout.tab_list_item, arr_sort);
                    setListAdapter(list_adapter);

                  }

                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                            int arg3) {
                    }

                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    }
                });
```

Thanks to help me guys :)

Comment: ``wordArray[j].subSequence(0, textlength)`` looks suspicious (and is causing the crash), what are you trying to do on that line?

Comment: I want to say that my query (text entered on Edit Text) length is equals to a word in my array "wordarray" wich have the same length and same characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work any better if you change this line;

```
if(query.equalsIgnoreCase((String) wordArray[j].subSequence(0, textlength)))
```

with

```
if(query.equalsIgnoreCase(wordArray[j].substring(0,
                          Math.min(wordArray[j].length(), textlength))))
```

?